# Stream smartphone display to laptop wirelessly

Tags: stream, smartphone, vrone

I'm creating an app in Unity with the VR One SDK and I was wondering how I could stream the display from my phone(galaxy samsung S5) to my laptop wirelessly

Answer (score 0):

I'm using chromecast to stream to beamers or large screens for presentation purposes as this has the best performance.